# How does mapping a two qubit gate to a pyramid scheme like this work?

Tags: quantum-gate

In [this video](https://youtu.be/cobp2Sf5f3o?t=513) from the QHACK2019 event, Gavin Crooks is visualizing two qubit gates by using a 3D pyramid. How does this mapping process work and what is the reason to do it? I could not find any resources for this.

Here is the pyramid:
[image: 2]
Credits: Gavin Cooks, QHACK2019, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cobp2Sf5f3o

Comment: Wild guess: Could be related to the decomposition in Eq. (12) here: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0011050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[(Zhang, 2002)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209120) introduces the above object (referred to as a Weyl chamber) and describes how it works, and Gavin Crooks provides a more accessible overview in a writeup [here](https://threeplusone.com/pubs/on_gates.pdf).

The basic idea is that you can synthesize any two-qubit gate using local operations and a parameterized 2-qubit unitary $V$ given as:
$$
V(c_x, c_y, c_z) = \exp\left(i \frac{\pi}{2} (c_x X\otimes X + c_y Y\otimes Y + c_z Z\otimes Z)\right)
$$
Due to periodicity we need only consider parameters in a unit cube $(c_x, c_y, c_z)\in[0, 1]^3$, and many choices of parameters produce the same $V$. An example given in (Zhang, 2002) is:
$$
V \left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\right) \sim  V \left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}\right) \sim \sqrt{\text{SWAP}}
$$
where "$\sim$" here means that the gates are equivalent up to additional local operations. Combining all of these symmetries allows you to reduce the cube of parameters to a tetrahedron of parameters, and the coordinates of gates on this tetrahedron are the parameters $(c_x, c_y, c_z)$ for the corresponding gate $V$ that they are equivalent to up to local operations. Importantly, after accounting for all the symmetries none of the gates in the Weyl chamber are equivalent to eachother up to local operations, so this system provides a nice way of classifying two-qubit gates that all differ in some fundamental way.